# Condition on values of target variable in Regression modelling

Tags: r, regression

Is it possible to produce a regression model, preferably in `R`, wherein we could specify conditions on the range the `target variable` could take. Like, `target variable >= 0`.
In my model, I'm trying to make a rough estimates of `customer orders` based on some categorical variables. It is quite obvious this variable can't be negative, but prediction of some of the entries are negative.

Comment: One easy fix is taking log of your target and then making predictions. After you have predictions, exponentiate them to get a value that is positive. Seems more natural to me than setting a hard threshold at zero.

Comment: Sure, I'll try this out.

Comment: I second @YairDaon's suggestion. Another approach is to switch to an approach like Poisson regression (which seems appropriate in your case), since it is inherently constrained to be positive.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Both of your answers seems to be a good solution to the problem i'm looking at. If instead of `target variable >= 0` and it being `-10 < target variable < 10`, is there a generalized solution to this? or just take in whatever is the estimate made by the model and set it to the closest limit, if it goes out of bounds?

Comment: I wouldn't use hard thresholds (though others may). I suggest mapping your constraint to the real axis *in a way that makes sense for your problem* and doing inference there.